# Multiple bookings across multiple tabs of a browser

Tags: php, codeigniter, payu

I am working on a play management application. I want to implement the following:

1. In one tab of a browser, user can book the seats and proceed to payment gateway and make payment.
2. If he opens another tab in the browser then he must be allowed to book other seats and make payment for the selected seat(s) in the current browser.

But currently I have implemented using sessions concept and if user is booking tickets in one tab, and if he makes an attempt to open the site in other tab and books ticket, I simply throw an alert that a transaction is going on currently and give him an option to end the transaction and start a new one. 
I am using PHP codeigniter framework

Comment: Show us the code that you have tried, the error that is occuring, and the desired output. Sounds like you need to change how you handle the user being in a session.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than storing the session in php you may need to store it in the html as a hidden variable and evaluate it in php to identify the session.

This may be your only option since both php sessions and cookies will not differentiate between different tabs.

You should consider the security implications of this approach based on your system and requirements.